# Out of memory only on PHP 7

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I just migrate to PHP 7 and always get 'out of memory' error while processing some function. I even tried memory limit to unlimited (memory_limit = -1) but the result is always same.
But when I go back to PHP 5.6, the problem is gone. I really have no idea what cause this.

here nusoap.php if anyone want to see what is really wrong
https://github.com/pouyadarabi/nusoap/blob/master/nusoap.php

here the error message

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Out of memory (allocated 226492416) (tried to allocate 71307096 bytes) in <b>C:\ValidasiFeeder\www\validasi\application\libraries\lib\nusoap.php</b> on line <b>256</b><br />

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Error</p>
<p>Message:  Out of memory (allocated 226492416) (tried to allocate 71307096 bytes)</p>
<p>Filename: lib/nusoap.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 256</p>
```

Comment: 32-bit PHP5.6;64-bit PHP7?

Comment: I am using 32 bit on both version

Comment: Can you at least provide some php code? Maybe the lines around `lib/nusoap.php:256`

Comment: nusoap.php has 8106 lines, line 256 just $this->debug_str .= $string; , it's a huge library of code

Comment: you sure the .ini files aren't from the previous install? make sure you're using the right system files.

Comment: That's a nice error-message, but without the actual code causing the error, we can't really help you.

Comment: Just to be sure, try placing `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1);` in your PHP file

Comment: maybe if you want to see inside nusoap.php , here https://github.com/pouyadarabi/nusoap/blob/master/nusoap.php

Comment: @Effe, yes I'm sure I did that, I even try to echo ini_get('memory_limit');, and the result is -1 for real ..

Comment: and did you restart everything after making any change to system files?

Comment: or maybe I should just stick on php 5.6 for this web app.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes of course, because it's the basic think ..

Comment: I like the comments around that line, "*it would be nice to use a memory stream here to use memory more efficiently*".

Comment: @BillyOrigin _"give up is not an option"_

Comment: again; make sure the path(s) to the system files weren't pointing to the previous version, I've seen that happen quite a few times before. Check your system `phpinfo()`.